# How to execute action after DialogFragment positive button clicked

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-dialogfragment

I created the following DialogFragment deriving it from the Android documentation:

public class PayBillDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        final Bundle b = this.getArguments();
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Paga bollettino")
               .setPositiveButton("Paga", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!


                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancella", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();

    }





}
```

From another Fragment (a ListFragment), when a row of the list is clicked the DialogFragment should be opened and after pressing the positive button of the DialogFragment I want to be able to remove the selected row of the ListFragment and also to call a method to perform a remote action associated to the removal. 
I implemented the ListFragment as follows:

```
public static class ListFragment extends android.support.v4.app.ListFragment {



        ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_view,
                    container, false);


            ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            }});
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    listItems);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            return rootView;
        }



        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {



            //opening the dialogfragment


        }


    }




    }
```

What I don't know is how to handle the action after the click of the positive button of the DialogFragment. Can you help me?

EDIT: to clarify, this is the workflow: click on the list -> show the DialogFragment -> after click on DialogFragment remove the element from the list.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I handle communication between fragment and dialog fragment

Example fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int REQ_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
                dialog.setTargetFragment(MainFragment.this, REQ_CODE);
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result: " + resultCode,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Example DialogFragment:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("My dialog message")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        notifyToTarget(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                notifyToTarget(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                            }
                        });
        return builder.create();
    }

    private void notifyToTarget(int code) {
        Fragment targetFragment = getTargetFragment();
        if (targetFragment != null) {
            targetFragment.onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), code, null);
        }
    }

}
```

This is the only method I got working also when changing orientation.

Answer (score 2):

You've got two options to call the `ListFragment` from `PayBillDialogFragment`.

**First** one is recommended by the Android guidelines. All the communication goes through the hosting `Activity`. That's how you get the hosting `Activity` by  calling `((HostingActivity)PayBillDialogFragment.getActivity()).deleteItem()` inside `PayBillDialogFragment.setPositiveButton(onClick())`. In `HostingActivity.deleteItem()` get the inflated `PayBillDialogFragment` and call some delete method in it.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks

**Second**. You can just `DialogFragment.setTargetFragment()` when creating the DialogFragment object and then inside `PayBillDialogFragment.setPositiveButton(onClick())` you can get `PayBillDialogFragment` by `DialogFragment.getTargetFragment()` and call the delete method there.

See [Callback to a Fragment from a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment)

Answer (score 0):

The List Fragment would be using an Adapter to show elements. The adapter requires input in the form of some Collection. So, what you can do is, when the user presses say ok button on dialog fragment and you communicate that back to List Fragment, you can remove that particular element from the Collection and again set the Adapter of List Fragment with modified collection.