# Issue in Button Text change from Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

Here there is minor issue Like I had Recyclerview in dialog fragment.ie name of bank in recyclerview When we select one bank in recyclerview and after dialogfragment dismiss that name should be appear on Button ie when we selected **Union Bank** from dialog fragment it should appear on button.**Issue is when we click on button then its text changes rather then on time of dismiss listener**

here is Dialog dismissal code:

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getContext(), mRecyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, final int position) {
            Employee e = bank.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getBank_id() + "" + e.getBank_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getDialog().setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                    Employee e = bank.get(position);
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("bankname", e.getBank_name());
                    edit.commit();
                }
            });
            c.onItemSelect(e.getBank_name());
            onDismiss(getDialog());
        }
```

Here is onclick event where dialog opens and where the value should be printed:

```
select_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
            DialogRecyclerview dr = new DialogRecyclerview(AccountManagement_banks.this,callback);
            dr.setRetainInstance(true);
            dr.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
            SharedPreferences st = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AccountManagement_banks.this);
            String mode=st.getString("bankname","");
            select_button.setText(mode);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),mode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Same in:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelect(String text) {
    select_button.setText(text);
}
```

Here I had created new Interface:

```
 public interface CallBack {
      void onItemSelect(String text);}
```

Comment: does your listview inside your fragemnt or it is in same Activity where your button ?

Comment: Pass any handler or custom listener interface when initializing DialogRecyclerview.

Comment: can you show me demo @pradeep sir

Comment: @dipalishah but clicklistener is in activity and ondismisslistener is on dialogfragment I want to settext on activity from dialogfragment

Comment: @sushildlh when select button is clicked the dialogfragment opens up and in that there is listview of bank and when we select bank the (select button) should be replaced by (selected bank)

Comment: @Abhi Use **OnActivityResult** to set the Text of button.

Comment: Can you eloborate little more.StartActivityForResult on dialogrecyclerview and onactivityresult on Activity??

Comment: @Abhi Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970196/how-to-execute-action-after-dialogfragment-positive-button-clicked

Comment: Still not coming @dipalishah there is no change in button either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just create a callback and implement it on your main class (where you want to display the name) and pass the callback instance to adapter. Now dialog fragment, now when you are selecting any item just call callback function which is overridden in main calss and inside this function just change the text of your button.

```
public interface CallBack {

void onItemSelect(String text);

}
```

implement this in your main class like

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CallBack {
.
.
.
public void onItemSelect(String text){
  button.setText(text);
}
.
.
}
```

when you are opening your dialogfragment from your main activity just pass **MainActivity.this** as an argument in the dialog constructor. And in your Dialog class constructor write your code like this

```
private Callback callback;
public YourDialog(Context context, Callback callback){
this.callback = callback;
}
```

and when you selecting list item just call

```
callback.onItemSelect(e.getBank_name());
```

Hope it will help you out.

Comment: I have changed my answer.

Comment: I had edited my Question Just watch it once I had used same things exactly you said still there is an error

Comment: in **select_button.setOnClickListener** you are sending **callback** where you have initalized it?

Comment: yeah initialization is coming from dialog fragment and text should be change of select_button

Comment: just try to debug your code at **c.onItemSelect(e.getBank_name());** and let me know the value of **c** and **e.getBank_name()** at this point.

Comment: the value of c is null

Comment: that's why the value is not displaying. Have you followed the same steps as I have written above?

Comment: you can see in main program which i had edited...i had used exactly wat u told

Comment: in the dialog constructor you have initialize the callback object, as I have done in **YourDialog**?

Comment: public DialogRecyclerview(Context context, CallBack c) {
        this.context=context;
        this.c = c;
    }

Comment: **select_button** is in your MainActivity?

Comment: Yeah exactly and want to change text of select_button

Comment: ok. In **DialogRecyclerview dr = new DialogRecyclerview(AccountManagement_banks.this,callback);** how you are getting **callback** value?

Comment: I think this is null. Just pass **AccountManagement_banks.this** in place of **callback.

Comment: like **DialogRecyclerview dr = new DialogRecyclerview(AccountManagement_banks.this, AccountManagement_banks.this);**

Comment: its value comes from **c.onItemSelect(e.getBank_name());** isnt it

Comment: no. You are doing wrong here. Just read my last 2 comments and do the same.