# Automatically disable/enable a listener based on its Fragment visibility

Tags: android, android-fragments, listener, android-fragmentactivity, onitemclicklistener

In an Android app, I have **two fragments**:

1. a fragment with a **ListView** of items
2. a fragment with an **ImageView**

Through callback onListItemSelected, when a user clicks on a ListView item, MainActivity pushes the ImageView on the stack and the fragment with the image appears on the screen. At this point I would expect that, since the ListView fragment is no longer visible, any events associated to this fragment are no longer fired. This is not the case. If I touch the ImageView, the listeners of the ListView items still fire.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to **automatically** enable/disable listeners based on their Fragment visibility?
2. If not, I guess the way to go would be to disable the ListView fragment view and then re-enable it when the backButton is pressed. How can I capture the backButton event in the MainActivity to re-enable a previously disabled view?

> public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
>    ListViewFragment.Callbacks {
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>        public void onListItemSelected(String str) {
>
>
>           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
>           FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();       
>
>           fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
>           fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listView, f);
>           fragmentTransaction.commit();
>
>           // disable listView 
>           //View lw = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listView).getView().findViewById(R.id.my_listView);
>           //lw.setEnabled(false);
>
>        }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try two things

1. Set the ImageView to consume touch events.

   `ImageView.setClickable(true);`
2. When pushing the new fragment disable touch events on the ListView.

   `ListView.setClickable(false);`

If you want to know how to know when the fragment with the ImageView is removed try setTargetFragment. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733914/935421

Comment: I decided to use the first solution as I didn't manage to make the second one working. The ImageView is now not clickable. However, I noticed something odd. If I tap the ImageView with multiple fingers sometimes this info appears in LogCat: "ACTION_DOWN before UnsetPressedState. invoking mUnsetPressedState.run()". It doesn't seem to create any issue though.