# Interactive map android v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-dialogfragment, android-maps-v2, infowindow

I want to build an interactive Android map app. It will have different marker types and lots of of different options when clicking on them.

First approach :
I started with the notion I will use custom infowindows but figured out that a map can have only single InfoWindowAdapter, with that said, this approach has another fault. InfoWindows can't have click listeners registered to them and I need to have some clickable UI to show after marker click.

Second approach :
Marker click triggers an alertDialog which corresponds to the marker type. I'm hesitant because I'll have lots of switch case inside the OnActivityResult.
Example - [dialog fragments with OnActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733914/1824521)

Any other ideas ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: any explanation for the downvote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problem some time ago and I "hacked" it as follows:

```
mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker pMarker) {
        MarkerDescriptor descriptor = mMarkerDescriptorsMap.get(pMarker);
        mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(descriptor.getOnInfoWindowClickListener(MapActivity.this));     
        return descriptor.getInfoWindowView();
    }
}
```

MarkerDescriptor should be simple interface that will be implemented for each specific marker type:

```
public interface MarkerDescriptor {
    public View getInfoWindowView();
    public OnInfoWindowClickListener getOnInfoWindowClickListener(Context pContext);
}
```

And to keep the references:

```
private Map<Marker, MarkerDescriptor> mMarkerDescriptorsMap = new HashMap<Marker, MarkerDescriptor>();
```

Basics of this idea is that GoogleMap can have only one marker selected at the time, so when user chooses another marker, we change the listeners.

Comment: why pMarker.hideInfoWindow() ?

Comment: This is part of my app logic - if there is no defined action asociated with this InfoWindow, just hide it. Sorry, I should have cutted it out from sample.

Comment: So you switch the WindowInfoAdapter depending on the marker ? Does it hinder the performance ?

Comment: To be precise I change OnInfoWindowClickListener depending on the marker. Basically setting listeners is just updating references - it affects perfromance equaly to `variable = someOtherVariable;`.