# How to pass a value from an AlertDialog to a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a simple question: I'm in a class when I have an Alert Dialog. From this class I get a String value from another class. How can I pass this value to my Fragment? To my Fragment, NOT Activity.

Comment: Create an interface in alertDialog and implement the interface in your fragment.

Comment: I already tried it but crash with ClassCastException on:

MyInterface callback = (MyInterface) context;

Comment: @GiorgioMirini can you post snippets of code (to debug the error)? Using an interface is a clean way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Here's a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment

Comment: Dont typecast context. implement interface in fragment, send 'this' from fragment to alertdialog and initialise the MyInterface