# setting a dialog builder in a fragment

Tags: android

i want to set a dialog on one of my buttons, the button in question is bd. how do i go about it? i want a dialog to pop up with a no to cancel the button action and a yes to continue the action. how do i set that on the button. my code`

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mt, container, false);


       v.findViewById(R.id.bd).setOnClickListener(this);
       v.findViewById(R.id.mcall).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.sd).setOnClickListener(this);
        v.findViewById(R.id.ltss).setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.mcall:
            Intent intentcall = new Intent();
            intentcall.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "216"));//set the Uri
            startActivity(intentcall);
            break;

        case R.id.bd:

            String encodedHarsh2 = "*"+"461"  +  "*" +"1" +  "*" +"1"+ Uri.encode("#");
            intentcall = new Intent();
            intentcall.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + encodedHarsh2 ));//set the Uri
            startActivity(intentcall);
            break;

        case R.id.sd:
            String encodedHarsh3 = "*"+"461"  +  "*" +"5" +"*"+ "4"+   Uri.encode("#");
            intentcall = new Intent();
            intentcall.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + encodedHarsh3 ));//set the Uri
            startActivity(intentcall);
            break;
        case R.id.ltss:

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),lts.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;




        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: like this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: I had a look at your link but my confusion is my fragment isn't a dialog fragment.  I already implemented onclicklistener on the fragment

Comment: so when someone clicks the button (inside your onclick listener) you can do it there. Already written on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment

Comment: I have to confess that got me more confused

Comment: is there no way I can set the alertdialog within the already existing fragment?

Comment: no you don't want to do that believe me :-) make a separate `DialogFragment`

Comment: Have you seen the material dialog library on github? Works just fine from fragments, looks nice and is easy to configure. No need to reinvent the wheel :-)

Comment: can I get link to it?  @cYrixmorten

Comment: Just search android material dialog on Google and it will be one of the top results.