# Return result from DialogFragment to SupportMapFragment in android

Tags: android

I'm working on a map project and I need to return value from DialogFragment to a SupportMapFragment.

```
@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));
    markerClicked = false;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    DataImportDialog pdf = DataImportDialog.newInstance("Enter Something");
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putDouble("Lat", point.latitude);
    args.putDouble("Lng", point.longitude);
    pdf.setArguments(args);
    pdf.show(ft, "PROMPT_DIALOG_TAG");

}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **interface** to communicate between two fragments or activity. here is good example in [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Or there is way using **setTargetFragment(Fragment fragment,int requestCode)** so that you can get fragment instance in your replaced or added fragment and you can call **onActivityResult** with bundle.. more about this on [developer doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment(android.app.Fragment,%20int))

here is complete example of same
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13733914/942224