# Return value from DialogFragment to other acivity

Tags: android, dialogfragment

this is my dialog-fragment. below you can see the String selection that keep the result after i choose from list of numbers from the dialog.
How can i save this value in other activity?

```
final   CharSequence[] items= {"1","2","3","4"};

String selection;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){



    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("CHOOSE YOUR ITEM TO DELETE").setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
                case 0:
                    selection=(String) items[which];
                    break;
                case 1:
                    selection=(String) items[which];
                    break;
                case 2:
                    selection=(String) items[which];
                    break;


            }

        }
    }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your item to delete is  "+ selection,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }




    });
    return builder.create();
```

}

}

Answer (score 0):

Define a listener/callback and have the other `Activity` implement and react to selections in this `DialogFragment`. StackOverflow contains many examples of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Define a public method in your `Activity` and and a private `variable` like below.

```
private String mString;

public setString(String s)
{
   this.mString = s;
}
```

And when user clicks button get activity and set the selected string like below:

```
((YourActivity)getActivity).setString(selectedString);
```

Than you can pass the string to other activities with `Bundle`.

If you show this `DialogFragment` from many activities you can define a `Listener` and implement on your activity.

```
public interface SelectionListener{
   void onStringSelected(String s);
}

((SelectionListener)getActivity).onStringSelected(selectedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

For permanently saving :-
For permanently saving your value among activities you can use database say sqlite .
For temporary saving :-
1. For these you have an option of global ArrayList and by that you can store .
2.You  can use callback as described here and these is almost same problem as you have [Callback to a Fragment from a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment)

you
 can see these example also for more details http://www.kylebeal.com/blog/2011/11/android-datepickerdialog-and-the-dialogfragment/