# Trying to get callbacks from DialogFragment to a fragment but the app is crashing

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, android-dialogfragment

My app's `MainActivity` has a `ViewPager` which has three children(swipe views). When swiped to last child, the `ActionBar` gets two `menu` items. On clicking one item, a `Dialog` pops up to add a name of an item into a `Database`. On clicking second `menu` item, another `Dialog` pops up that prompts user to enter the name of the item that is to be removed from the `Database`. These `Dialogs` are getting constructed by separate `Dialog` `Fragments`. Basically what I want is to get the `callback` event from the `Dialog` that the positive or negative button has been clicked and wanna perform some action in the fragment which is as I mentioned is the last child of my `ViewPager`. I've seen the `Android` documentation as well as a Youtube video to learn how to implement the interface, yet my app's crashing.

**Here's the code for my `DialogFragment` which shows a `Dialog` that prompts the user to enter input and save it to the `Database`.**

```
package com.example.android.mybusiness;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddCigaretteNameDialog extends DialogFragment {

    EditText userInput;
    String cigaretteName;
    DbHelper dbHelper;

    public AddCigaretteNameDialogListener listener;

    public interface AddCigaretteNameDialogListener {
        void onDialogPositiveClick(String name);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dbHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // SET THE TITLE FOR THE DIALOG.
        builder.setTitle(R.string.add_title);
        // GET THE LAYOUT INFLATOR
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        // INFLATE THE LAYOUT AND PUT IT INTO A VARIABLE.
        // PASS NULL AS PARENT VIEW, BECAUSE IT'S GOING IN THE DIALOG
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_for_dialogs, null);
        // GET THE EDIT_TEXT FROM THE 'VIEW' VARIABLE.
        userInput = view.findViewById(R.id.cigarette_name_user_input);
        // SET THE LAYOUT FOR THE DIALOG
        builder.setView(view);
        // SET ACTION BUTTONS
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    // GET THE USER INPUT FROM THE EDIT_TEXT ABOVE AND PUT IT INTO A VARIABLE.
                    cigaretteName = userInput.getText().toString();
                    // PUT THE USER INPUT IN THE DATABASE.
                    Boolean result = dbHelper.insertCigaretteName(cigaretteName);
                    if (result) {

                        // SHOW SUCCESS MESSAGE THAT CIGARETTE NAME HAS BEEN INSERTED.
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), cigaretteName + " has been added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        listener.onDialogPositiveClick(cigaretteName);



                    } else {Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });



        // RETURN THE DIALOG.
        return builder.create();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        // VERIFY THAT THE HOST ACTIVITY IMPLEMENTS THE CALLBACK INTERFACE
        try {
            listener = (AddCigaretteNameDialogListener) getTargetFragment();
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            // THE ACTIVITY DOESN'T IMPLEMENT INTERFACE, THROW AN EXCEPTION.
            throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString() + " must implement listener");
        }

    }
}
```

**And here's the fragment which is the last child of the view pager.**

```
package com.example.android.mybusiness;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Purchase extends Fragment implements AddCigaretteNameDialog.AddCigaretteNameDialogListener {
    Spinner spinner;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;



    // FRAGMENT'S CONSTRUCTOR.
    public Purchase() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // KIND OF REQUIREMENT FOR OPTION MENUS.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // INSTANTIATING THE OBJECT TO RUN A FUNCTION, WHICH GETS THE CIGARETTES NAME.
        dbHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // AND PUT IT INTO A VARIABLE SO WIDGETS CAN BE ACCESSED.
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_purchase, container, false);
        // FIND THE spinner.
        spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        // CREATING THIS ADAPTER TO POPULATE THE SPINNER WIDGET.
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dbHelper.getAllCigaretteNames());

        // SETTING THE ADAPTER TO THE SPINNER, WHICH WILL PROVIDE THE CONTENT TO BE SELECTED BY ME.
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_cigarette:
                AddCigaretteNameDialog addCigaretteNameDialog = new AddCigaretteNameDialog();
                addCigaretteNameDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "add_cigarette_name");
                return true;
            case R.id.remove_cigarette:
                RemoveCigaretteNameDailog RemoveCigaretteNameDailog = new RemoveCigaretteNameDailog();
                RemoveCigaretteNameDailog.show(getFragmentManager(), "add_cigarette_name");
            ;    return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(String name) {
        arrayAdapter.add(name);
    }
}
```

**Here's the crash log:**

> 12-07 13:13:59.278 25327-25327/com.example.android.mybusiness
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.android.mybusiness, PID: 25327
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void
>   com.example.android.mybusiness.AddCigaretteNameDialog$AddCigaretteNameDialogListener.onDialogPositiveClick(java.lang.String)'
>   on a null object reference
>           at com.example.android.mybusiness.AddCigaretteNameDialog$2.onClick(AddCigaretteNameDialog.java:58)
>           at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:162)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)

**Line 58 is**

> listener.onDialogPositiveClick(cigaretteName);

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your crash log is getTargetFragment() is null?

Comment: post your crash log

Comment: I'll just post it. Gimme few minutes

Comment: done updating with crash log.

Comment: addCigaretteNameDialog.setTargetFragment(Purchase.this,0) add this line before  addCigaretteNameDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "add_cigarette_name");

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733304/callback-to-a-fragment-from-a-dialogfragment?rq=1   refer this if you have more doubt

Comment: I'll just try it in couple of minutes. AS is being opened. :)

Comment: It is showing error saying "getTarhetFragment() in Fragment can't be applied to (com.example.android.mybusiness.Purchase, int)"

Comment: Bro you know what, the reference of yours worked! But not the checked answer. Thanks for your help! N I checked it before posting my question. Since I couldn't understand it, I left it. Really need to work hard to be a good developer. Don't I?

Comment: it will come with experience bro. cool. glad it helps. cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom dialog class with custom view this would solve your problem. I am posting a code below which shows a custom dialog with views. first of all create a layout file for your dialog design by name `dlg_add_cigarette_name` inside `layout` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_background_inset"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="Cigrate Name:"
    android:id="@+id/tv_label_total"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout_total_update"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_label_total"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/et_cgrate_name"
        android:inputType="text"
        />
</LinearLayout>



<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_total_update"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
    android:text="OK"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_ok"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout_total_update"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_ok"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    />
```

Now inside drawable folder create a new file by name `dialog_background_inset`and update the file by following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@color/white"
    android:insetRight="15dp"
    android:insetLeft="15dp">
</inset>
```

and now in your `AddCigaretteNameDialog` file update the class by following code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.drinkwater.reminder.watertracker.R;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.Unbinder;


public class AddCigaretteNameDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private static final float DIM_AMOUNT = 0.4f;
    @BindView(R.id.tv_label_total)
    TextView tvLabelTotal;
    @BindView(R.id.et_cgrate_name)
    EditText etCgrateName;
    @BindView(R.id.layout_total_update)
    LinearLayout layoutTotalUpdate;
    @BindView(R.id.button_ok)
    Button buttonOk;
    @BindView(R.id.button_cancel)
    Button buttonCancel;

    @OnClick(R.id.button_cancel)
    public void onClick(){
        dismiss();
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.button_ok)
    public void onClickOkay(){
        unitCallBack.addCigarette(cigaretteName);
    }



    private Unbinder mUnbinder;
    private AddCigaretteName unitCallBack;

    private String cigaretteName;



    public AddCigaretteNameDialog() {
    }

    public static AddCigaretteNameDialog newInstance(String title) {
        AddCigaretteNameDialog frag = new AddCigaretteNameDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (unitCallBack == null && context instanceof AddCigaretteName) {
            unitCallBack = (AddCigaretteName) context;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        unitCallBack = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        final Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams windowLayoutParams = window.getAttributes();
            windowLayoutParams.dimAmount = DIM_AMOUNT;
        }
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
        mUnbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        etCgrateName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                cigaretteName=s.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final int width = getScreenWidth();
        int height = getScreenHeight() / 2;
        changeWindowSizes(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    private void changeWindowSizes(int width, int height) {
        final Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        if (window != null) {
            window.setLayout(width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mUnbinder.unbind();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTheme() {
        return R.style.CustomDialog;
    }

    public interface AddCigaretteName {
        void addCigarette(String name);
    }

    public static int getScreenWidth() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }

    public static int getScreenHeight() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    }
}
```

create a custom theme inside styles file

```
 <style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/CustomDialogAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/translate_left_side</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/translate_right_side</item>
    </style>
```

create a package `anim` inside `res`folder and create two files `translate_left_side`and `translate_right_side` 
**translate_right_side**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="600"/>
```

**translate_left_side**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"/>
```

Your `AddCigrateDialog` is ready to appear.Now its time to call this dialog from button click.Inside `Purchase` make an object of `AddCigaretteDialog` class globally

```
AddCigaretteNameDialog addCigaretteNameDialog;

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add_cigarette:
                 addCigaretteNameDialog= new AddCigaretteNameDialog();            
                 addCigaretteNameDialog= AddCigaretteNameDialog.newInstance("AddCigrateNameDialog");
                 addCigaretteNameDialog.show(manager,"show");
                return true;
            case R.id.remove_cigarette:
                RemoveCigaretteNameDailog RemoveCigaretteNameDailog = new RemoveCigaretteNameDailog();
                RemoveCigaretteNameDailog.show(getFragmentManager(), "add_cigarette_name");
            ;    return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

And yes don't forget to  implement the interface of `AddCigaretteDialog` inside `Purchase` dialog

As I am using `ButterKnife` dependency add the following lines inside your app's gradle file

```
inal BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION = "8.8.1"
implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTER_KNIFE_VERSION"
```

Comment: Actually comments right below my question worked. Thanks for your help though. I really appreciate it buddy.