# How can I pass a listener from a Fragment to a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-mvp

I'm currently working in a single activity application that is using fragments for each screen. I'm also using MVP design pattern.

**Context**

- I have a Fragment (Fragment-A) in which I have a List of Items. 
  This Fragment handles the actions for each of the items. Because it has access to the presenter.
- I have a DialogFragment (Fragment-B) in which you can fill some checkboxes and complete an action (This is action is handled in the Fragment-A which implements an interface for this)
- I'm using a bundle to create DialogFragment. (I can't pass the listener as an argument)

**What I want?**

How can I pass Fragment-A as a Listener to the DialogFragment (Fragment-B), so I can call the actions from the DialogFragment?

Comment: okay, short asnwer, use an interface which implements Parcelable,implement tin Frag A (also override read and writeToParcel, no need add logic inside) and  then pass the listener(interface) through bundle when you creating instance of DialogFrag, and receive it on your Dialog Frgment's onCreate() ,

Comment: You can check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68572828/3586084)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your `DialogFragment` is a child fragment of the other Fragment (you're passing in `getChildFragmentManager()` to `show()`) as it should be, then your `FragmentA` will get a callback to [`onAttachFragment()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttachFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)):

> Called when a fragment is attached as a child of this fragment.

This gives you a reference to the child DialogFragment, where you can then set any listener you want.

Comment: What happens if I exit the application while the DialogFragment is showed and returned to the app after the app is no longer in memory? The listener won't be set then.

Comment: You'll get a new call to `onAttachFragment`.